# How to make an element div (coming soon clock) resposive?

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, response

I want to create a Responsive coming soon one page [website](https://unripened-amperes.000webhostapp.com/index.HTML)

and i found how to make logo/image responsive using this course [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_responsive.asp)

but i could not figure out how to make the clock coming soon element/div resposive espacially for [mobile](https://www.responsinator.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Funripened-amperes.000webhostapp.com%2Findex.HTML)

because as you see the clock is bigger then logo in mobile version .
So how can i make the coming soon clock smaller in mobile version ?

```css
.responsive {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.logo{
  width:60%;
  margin: auto;
}



#cssload-wrapper {
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.cssload-loader {
 width: 225px;
 height: 225px;
 border: 2px rgb(245,131,32) solid;
 position: relative;
 /* left: 50%;
 top: 65%; */
 margin: 0;
 border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-loading {
 font-size: 15px;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 21px;
 font-family: 'Century Gothic', sans-serif;
 font-style: italic;
 left: 0;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: 30px;
 color: rgb(0,101,179);
 font-weight: bold;
 text-transform: uppercase;
  -o-text-transform: uppercase;
  -ms-text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-text-transform: uppercase;
  -moz-text-transform: uppercase;
}

.cssload-loader-circle-1 {
 width: 207px;
 height: 207px;
 left: 8px;
 top: 8px;
 border: 2px rgb(0,101,179) solid;
 position: absolute;
 border-right-color: transparent;
 border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 animation: spin 3.45s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: spin 3.45s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: spin 3.45s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: spin 3.45s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spin 3.45s linear infinite;
}

.cssload-loader-circle-2 {
 width: 189px;
 height: 189px;
 left: 8px;
 top: 8px;
 border: 2px transparent solid;
 position: absolute;
 border-right-color: rgb(245,131,32);
 border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 animation: spin 5.75s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: spin 5.75s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: spin 5.75s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: spin 5.75s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spin 5.75s linear infinite;
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-line {
 width: 15px;
 height: 3px;
 background: rgb(0,101,179);
 position: absolute;
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-line:nth-child(1) {
 left: 24px;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -2px;
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-line:nth-child(2) {
 transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
 left: 50px;
 top: 50px;
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-line:nth-child(3) {
 top: 24px;
 left: 50%;
 width: 3px;
 height: 15px;
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-line:nth-child(4) {
 transform: rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
 right: 50px;
 top: 50px;
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-line:nth-child(5) {
 right: 24px;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -2px;
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-line:nth-child(6) {
 transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
 right: 50px;
 bottom: 50px;
 background: rgb(245,131,32);
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-subline {
 position: absolute;
 width: 5px;
 height: 3px;
 background: rgb(0,101,179);
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-subline:nth-child(7) {
 transform: rotate(22.5deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(22.5deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(22.5deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(22.5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(22.5deg);
 left: 32px;
 top: 75px;
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-subline:nth-child(8) {
 transform: rotate(67.5deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(67.5deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(67.5deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(67.5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(67.5deg);
 left: 75px;
 top: 32px;
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-subline:nth-child(9) {
 transform: rotate(112.5deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(112.5deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(112.5deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(112.5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(112.5deg);
 right: 75px;
 top: 32px;
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-subline:nth-child(10) {
 transform: rotate(157.5deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(157.5deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(157.5deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(157.5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(157.5deg);
 right: 32px;
 top: 75px;
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-subline:nth-child(11) {
 transform: rotate(22.5deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(22.5deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(22.5deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(22.5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(22.5deg);
 right: 30px;
 bottom: 74px;
 background: rgb(0,101,179);
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-needle {
 width: 21px;
 height: 21px;
 border: 2px rgb(0,101,179) solid;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 margin: -12px 0 0 -12px;
 z-index: 1;
 border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 animation: pegIt 3.45s infinite ease-in-out;
  -o-animation: pegIt 3.45s infinite ease-in-out;
  -ms-animation: pegIt 3.45s infinite ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation: pegIt 3.45s infinite ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation: pegIt 3.45s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-needle:before {
 content: "";
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 5.5px 75px 5.5px 0;
 border-color: transparent rgb(245,131,32) transparent transparent;
 position: absolute;
 right: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 margin: -5.5px 0 0 0;
 border-radius: 0 50% 50% 0;
  -o-border-radius: 0 50% 50% 0;
  -ms-border-radius: 0 50% 50% 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 50% 50% 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 50% 50% 0;
}





@keyframes pegIt {
 0% {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 16% {
  transform: rotate(75deg);
 }
 25% {
  transform: rotate(55deg);
 }
 30% {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
 }
 36% {
  transform: rotate(170deg);
 }
 42% {
  transform: rotate(150deg);
 }
 50% {
  transform: rotate(227deg);
 }
 100% {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
}

@-o-keyframes pegIt {
 0% {
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 16% {
  -o-transform: rotate(75deg);
 }
 25% {
  -o-transform: rotate(55deg);
 }
 30% {
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
 }
 36% {
  -o-transform: rotate(170deg);
 }
 42% {
  transform: rotate(150deg);
 }
 50% {
  -o-transform: rotate(227deg);
 }
 100% {
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
}

@-ms-keyframes pegIt {
 0% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 16% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(75deg);
 }
 25% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(55deg);
 }
 30% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
 }
 36% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(170deg);
 }
 42% {
  transform: rotate(150deg);
 }
 50% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(227deg);
 }
 100% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes pegIt {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 16% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(75deg);
 }
 25% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(55deg);
 }
 30% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
 }
 36% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(170deg);
 }
 42% {
  transform: rotate(150deg);
 }
 50% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(227deg);
 }
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes pegIt {
 0% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 16% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(75deg);
 }
 25% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(55deg);
 }
 30% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
 }
 36% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(170deg);
 }
 42% {
  transform: rotate(150deg);
 }
 50% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(227deg);
 }
 100% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
}

@keyframes spin {
 0% {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 100% {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
}

@-o-keyframes spin {
 0% {
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 100% {
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
}

@-ms-keyframes spin {
 0% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 100% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
 0% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 100% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
<img class='responsive' src='https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-VTCVnBuSn3I/XAxJCeM2HeI/AAAAAAAAAuw/vddRM_bPEgQwkXeFbQ5Uwgd5wlRDwpWPQCLcBGAs/s1600/600.PNG'/>
   </div>

<div id="cssload-wrapper" align="center">
 <div class="cssload-loader">
  <div class="cssload-line"></div>
  <div class="cssload-line"></div>
  <div class="cssload-line"></div>
  <div class="cssload-line"></div>
  <div class="cssload-line"></div>
  <div class="cssload-line"></div>
  <div class="cssload-subline"></div>
  <div class="cssload-subline"></div>
  <div class="cssload-subline"></div>
  <div class="cssload-subline"></div>
  <div class="cssload-subline"></div>
  <div class="cssload-loader-circle-1"><div class="cssload-loader-circle-2"></div></div>
  <div class="cssload-needle"></div>
  <div class="cssload-loading">COMING SOON</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp). You can resize your `<div>` elements according to the browser window's size.

Like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .cssload-wrapper{
    width: 300px;
  }
}
```